# Building .car ColdFusion Archive from command-line

Tags: command-line, coldfusion, package, coldfusion-11

The current way I'm packaging my application is to deploy it on a running ColdFusion server, and export is as a `.car` (Coldfusion ARchive) through the admin console, but this manual process is usually prone to errors.

That's why I'm looking for a tool (or any solution) to build this final `.car` from the command line (so without requiring a ColdFusion server up and running).

**Note:** because of the complexity and the size of this legacy application, I cannot work with `.war` files, and I'm not aware of any other packaging format than `.war` or `.car` for ColdFusion applications.

Comment: You won't be able to make a `.car` file without using CF (either the admin UI or API). However all it really does it bundle up the contents of the config XML files (in `cfusion/lib`), as far as I know. You could just emulate that. Which settings you extract would be contingent on your needs.

Comment: The advantage of ```.car``` file is that is more convenient to deploy/track in the admin console for the IT. Can you give me more details about the API?

Comment: Actually the Admin API might not be able to help you. But here are the doc: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Using+the+ColdFusion+Administrator#UsingtheColdFusionAdministrator-AdministratorAPI. I see no reference to archiving in there at the top level. You might want to keep an eye on this Twittter thread (https://twitter.com/DAC_dev/status/556726813352030208) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Hi unfortunately Coldfusion is not built to use in this way but you can use API or the admin console.

I invite you to read this page : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fc5.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

From coldfusion 9 servers, CAR files are zip files. You can unzip them, edit the files, and zip them back up and deploy them on coldfusion10 servers.  The zip contains a folder called "{WorkingDir}" with curly brackets.

Structure looks like

    `{WorkingDir}
        server_settings.xml
        archive_settings.xml`